# chosen-select dropdown not working by jquery MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown, jquery-chosen

I'm using dropdown with multiple select with groups in my mvc razor page. I'm following below link and using **Multiple Select with Groups** dropdown.

[Harvest Multiselect Dropdown Link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/http://)

It is working fine if I implement in razor view like below sample:

```
....
<select data-placeholder="Search option" id="Mainlist[0].SubList" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6" name="MainList[0].SubList">
     <option value=""></option>
     @foreach (var mainListItem in Model.MainList)
     {
          <optgroup label="@mainListItem.Name">
           @foreach (var subListItem in mainListItem.SubList)
           {
               <option id="report">@subListItem.Name</option>
           }
           </optgroup>
      }
</select>
....
```

Above razor code for chosen dropdown working fine like in below image:
[image: razor chosen-select dropdown]

But I have a requirement to add more multi select dropdowns on button click event of jquery. I tried below code in jquery:

```
var newRow =
"<select data-placeholder='Search option' id='Mainlist[1].SubList' class='chosen-select' multiple tabindex='6' name='MainList[1].SubList'>" +
        "<option value=''></option>" +
        "<optgroup label='Main List Item 1'>" +
        "<option id='report'>Sub List Item 1.1</option>" +
        "<option id='report'>Sub List Item 1.2</option>" +
        "</optgroup>" +
        "<optgroup label='Main List Item 2'>" +
        "<option id='report'>Sub List Item 2.1</option>" +
        "<option id='report'>Sub List Item 2.2</option>" +
        "</optgroup>" +
        "</select>";

$('#TestTable tr:last').after(newRow);
```

First problem is : I can't implement foreach loop in newRow variable.
Second one is : If I try to manage whole list manually like above code, then also List is not coming properly like below image:
[image: jquery chosen-select dropdown]

Any idea what is causing it? and how can I make dropdown working by jquery? or is there any other way to add same dropdown by jquery?

I already tried $(".chosen-select").chosen() from below link:

[chosen-select link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811270/chosen-jquery-plugin-basic-ui-does-not-work)

Comment: Have you tried this? $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you are initializing the chosen after the select is added to dom. 
Could you tell me the error you are facing.

Comment: Hi Rishi. Thanks for quick answer. How can I initialize chosen? does it mean adding script again? 
So far I'm not getting any error, but jquery dropdown is coming as a list, not as a chosen dropdown like first image.

Comment: you need to initialize chosen using this code.  $(".chosen-select").chosen() . It seems you are appending the select into the dom dynamically. so please check you are initializing the chosen after it is appended to the dom.

Comment: wohooo it worked. Actually I tried it but in wrong place. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please refer the link  http://jsfiddle.net/Rishi0405/oj3cjw9w/297/ and also check whether you have add all the external resourced added in the fiddle